# Making text narrow

Tags: fonts, scaling, microtype, letterspacing

I'm using `\textls`from the `microtype` package to increase space between letters, but I can't find a command that will make a text look narrow (or maybe a very narrow serif font?).

What is the best way of giving a "compact" effect to a text?

Comment: If you're installing the font yourself, for instance `otftotfm` allows an option `extend` which can be used to make a condensed fornt.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

if the text that you want to be "narrow" is just short phrases, and they don't need to be broken into lines, you can cheat, and use `\scalebox` from the `graphicx` package.  for example:

[image: some text with part of it compressed horizontally]

the narrowed portion was produced with

```
\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{This text is narrowed.}
```

you do need the optional `[1.0]` height, since you want to change the aspect ratio.

it's not wonderful, and the limitations are, well, limiting, but it doesn't require anything you haven't already got.

Comment: Thank you. It is interesting indeed, although it distords the text a bit, but that's to be expected… I'll change the selected anwser to this one because it does answer the question best.

Comment: @Raphink -- i guess i'd say it distorts the text *more* than "a bit".  really, a condensed font would be your best option, and stephan lehmke's comment on the original question sounds quite plausible.  an example of a "cm" condensed font appears on p.35 in the article by knuth "[typesttting concrete mathematics](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-1/tb23knut.pdf)".  the metafont sources are on ctan; i don't believe there is a type 1 version.

Comment: I've just noticed that the space following the period in the narrowed text isn't the usual width, indicating that the `\scalebox` effectively hides the period.  How to rectify this isn't immediately obvious to me, but I'm thinking about it.

Answer (score 14):

`\textls` accepts an optional argument to specify the amount of letterspacing; the default value is 100 (i.e., each character is spaced out by 0.1em). It is possible to specify a negative value.

(I should point out that choosing a "narrow" font design is far better than this brute-force solution. Also, the value of `-35` in my example was chosen for demonstration purposes and borders the intolerable.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\textls[100]{\blindtext}%  or just \textls{\blindtext}

\textls[45]{\blindtext} 

\blindtext

\textls[-35]{\blindtext} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes the text more compact by removing spaces between letters. Do you know how the font could be compacted?

Comment: @Raphink: Sadly, no.

Answer (score 6):

You can also search for a font with a condensed set of characters

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[shrink=40,letterspace=500]{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\fontdimen2\font=1.5pt
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting. The result looks very similar to what I get with @lockstep's answer, it doesn't seem to really affect how narrow the letters are rendered, but rather reduce the spacing.